How do you apply a transformation, or a superposition in David Hetens' geometric formulation of the wavefunction?
In David Hestenes' formulation of the wavefunction in geometric algebra, we have:
$$
\psi(x) = \sqrt{\rho(x)} R(x) e^{-ib(x)/2}
$$
where R(x) is a rotor.
For simplicity, let us now consider a two-state system:
$$
|\psi \rangle = \pmatrix{ \sqrt{\rho_1} R_1 e^{-ib_1/2}  \\ \sqrt{\rho_2} R_2e^{-ib_2/2} }
$$
If I apply a transformation, such as a Hadamar matrix, I might get:
$$
|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pmatrix{ \sqrt{\rho_1} R_1 e^{-ib_1/2} +  \sqrt{\rho_2} R_2e^{-ib_2/2} \\  \sqrt{\rho_1} R_1 e^{-ib_1/2} -  \sqrt{\rho_2} R_2e^{-ib_2/2} }
$$
but now the problem is that the rotor part of $\sqrt{\rho_1} R_1 e^{-ib_1/2} +  \sqrt{\rho_2} R_2e^{-ib_2/2}$ are no longer in Spin(3,1), because Spin(3,1) is not closed under addition.
So a simple transformation can "break" the representation of the wavefunction outside the Spin(3,1) group.
Am I misunderstanding this? Are there extra transformation rules that disallow this. I wasn't able to find anything answer in Hestenes' body of work.

you are making some fundamental misunderstandings. The spin half two state system is fully represented by the probability density $\rho$ and the rotor $R$, so you should not have $\left|\psi\right>$ looking like that. The algebra of the rotor is closed, but it can be difficult to find the single rotor that equals the sum of two rotors.

@naturallyInconsistent But can you not have a superposition like $\lambda_1 \sqrt{\rho_1} R_1 e^{-ib_1/2} + \lambda_2 \sqrt{\rho_2} R_2 e^{-ib_2/2}$ like you do in QM? Also R are valued in Spin(3,1) and Spin(3,1) is most certainly not closed under addition, only under multiplication.

As I said, yes, you can. That turns out to be another $\sqrt\rho R$ but it is not obvious how to get it. It has to be so because we know we can decompose $\sqrt\rho R$ into the usual matrix form and that algebra is closed, and then there is a mapping between the matrix form and the rotor form, so there must be a solution.

@naturallyInconsistent a+f+b (the even subalgebra of GA(3,1), where a  is a scalar, f a bivector and b a pseudo-scalar is closed under addition. But the subset exp (a+f+b) isn't.

@naturallyInconsistent or is the form exp(a+f+b) not equivalent to $\psi=\sqrt{\rho}e^{-ib/2} R$, such that the latter is closed under addition, but not the former?

Not every rotor is a bivector exponential, so the form $\sqrt\rho e^{-bi/2}R$ is not the same as your $\exp(a+f+B)$. (I'm using $B$, a bivector, to contrast with $b$, a scalar.) Every even multivector can be put in the $\sqrt\rho e^{-bi/2}R$ form.
